Kobayashi - Second fundamental form on the orthogonal holomorphic subbundle
In Kobayashi https://www.mathsoc.jp/assets/pdf/publications/pubmsj/Vol15.pdf page 30, in the first line of the proof of Porposition 1.6.6. I do not understand how to obtain that $B$ is a $(0,1)$-form.
If $\eta\in A^0(S^{\perp})$ is a holomorphic section of $S^{\perp}$, then both sides of the identity $D\eta=D_{S^{\perp}}\eta+B\eta$  are $(1,0)$-forms. If $B\eta\in A^{1,0}(S)$ then how comes that $B\in A^{0,1}(Hom(S^{\perp},S))$  ???

I am also quite confused... On the one hand, it seems like $S$ and $S^{\perp}$ are completely interchangeable, so one would expect the second fundamental forms $A$ and $B$ to both be of same type $(1,0)$. On the other hand, the end of the proof of Proposition 1.6.6 clearly shows that $A$ and $B$ have opposite type as they are adjoint for the hermitian product....

@FrançoisGatine That is exactly my problem.

It makes no sense to talk about a holomorphic section of $S^\perp$, as you're using the hermitian metric to define this $C^\infty$ complex vector bundle. $S$ is a holomorphic bundle, however. In the smooth category, you can talk about interchangeability, but not in the holomorphic category.

@TedShifrin Right, if $S^{\perp}$ is holomorphic then the second fundamental form pretty much vanishes. But still that does not explain why $B$ is of type $(0,1)$. Can you explain that please?

Isn't that clear from the final line of the proof of the proposition? $h$ is conjugate-linear in the second factor.

@TedShifrin Yes it is but I would like to understand the first line of the proof, as it seems that you can get it from more general consideration

He is laying out the proof to come, not claiming anything is proved in that first sentence.
